# Displaying a footer below background-size:cover

Tags: html, css, background

I finally found a way to shrink a background image to cover the entire screen regardless of the size by using `background-size: cover`, but an unforeseen issue that cropped up was that it totally hid my footer behind the background image, because the background image is in a div above the footer. I've tried using `z-index`, but that didn't do anything. All the code can be found at http://hanksmith.com/, specifically at http://hanksmith.com/css/index.css and http://hanksmith.com/css/master.css. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why your CSS links are in the body tag? and your footer is having   `margin-top: 100%;` remove that.

Comment: The CSS links are a little skewed because I have a few different HTML pages all loading into the index.php page and I haven't gotten around to fixing it all yet. Thanks for the suggestions though, I'll try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved when you remove the footer `margin-top` in your `master.css`.

Try this:

```
.footer {
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. If you don't mind my asking, why did the margin-top make a difference? I guess I'm still pretty new when it comes to web coding.

Comment: no need to add `margin-top` since this will add another 100% screen height base on your screen.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to, that your background image not hide on footer so follow screen size. Like that this size images need ( 1366*768, 1920*1080, 3840*2160 ).